# dse spark-submit to specific work pool instead of "default"

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am able to successfully build the example project from https://github.com/datastax/SparkBuildExamples/tree/master/scala/sbt/dse/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/example

I am also successful in submitting dse spark-submit. The program runs fine and results are good as expected

`dse spark-submit --class com.datastax.spark.example.WriteRead target/writeRead-0.1.jar`

I now wish to submit it the above job to an existing pool as configured in dse.yaml

```
resource_manager_options:
worker_options:
    cores_total: 6
    memory_total: 32G
    workpools:
        - name: alwayson_sql
          cores: 2
          memory: 4G
        - name: pool_1
          cores: 2
          memory: 16G
```

I am unable to determine how/what changes in code or spark-submit that I should do in order to submit the application to the pool "pool_1"

The application is submitted to the default pool and I am unable to submit it to "pool_1".

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional research I figured out the correct way to dse spark-submit to use the pool "pool_1"

```
 bin/dse spark-submit \
 --master dse://?workpool=pool_1 \
 --conf spark.network.timeout=500 \
 --class com.datastax.spark.example.WriteRead target/writeRead-0.1.jar
```

(Per input from Alex)DSE Documentation:
[Documentation link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/startingSpark.html?hl=workpool#SpecifyingSparkURLs)

Comment: it's actually in the DSE documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/startingSpark.html?hl=workpool#SpecifyingSparkURLs

Comment: Thanks Alex for pointing out to the documentation. Is there a specific reason why --master dse://?workpool=<<pool_name>> (i.e. without specifying ip_address), I tried with the ip address of the master, DSE was throwing timeout warnings unable to get the setting.

Comment: it should work with IP just fine.  Often, people make a mistake by specifying port as 7077, but in DSE, all communications happen on port 9042

Comment: ok. That is what I was doing I guess.. using port 7077 and it was just timing out. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: if you didn't change anything, then just use IP, without port. I think that there is such example in the documentation